# Unhandled exception while trying to print some value

Tags: c++, arrays, exception, memory, output

I was writing my own implementation of `vector`, and when I was trying to print a number, some times I am getting an exception on the line in which I was trying to print it. I understand that the problem is located in memory, but I don't know why memory staying uninitialized when I do initialize it with my function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class badvector {
private:
    uint64_t _size;
    uint64_t _capacity;
    shared_ptr<T[]> arrptr;
    bool resizable;
    void initialize() {
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
            arrptr[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    void initialize(uint64_t sz, shared_ptr<T[]> &ptrarr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
            ptrarr[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    void capacity_count() {
        _capacity = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
            if (arrptr[i] != 0) {
                ++_capacity;
            }
        }
        if (_capacity > _size) {
            throw "error, capacity out of range";
        }
    }
public:
    explicit badvector() : _size(5), _capacity(0), arrptr(new T[5]), resizable(true) {
        initialize();
    }
    ~badvector() = default;
    uint64_t get_cp() {
        capacity_count(); 
        return this->_capacity;
    }
    uint64_t size() {
        return this->_size;
    }
    void push_back(T arg) {
        capacity_count();
        if (_capacity == _size) {
            resize(_size + 5);
        }
        arrptr[_capacity] = arg;
        ++this->_capacity; 
        capacity_count();
    }
    void reserve(uint64_t sz) {
        _size = sz;
        if (!resizable) {
            throw "Error, you are not able to reserve any more place, you used resize";
        }
        capacity_count();
        shared_ptr<T[]> temp(new T[sz]);
        initialize(sz, temp);
        for (int i = 0; i < _capacity; i++) {
            temp[i] = arrptr[i];
        }
        arrptr = temp;
        capacity_count();
    }
    void resize(uint64_t sz) {
        reserve(sz);
        resizable = false;
    }
    T operator[](uint64_t position) {
        capacity_count();
        if (position >= _capacity || position < 0) {
            throw "badvector out of range";
        };
        return *(arrptr.get() + position);
    }
    void print(uint64_t num) {
        capacity_count();
        if (num >= _capacity || num < 0) {
            throw "badvector out of range";
        }
        cout << arrptr[num] << endl;
    }
    const T* cbegin() const {
        return arrptr.get();
    }
    T* begin(){
        return arrptr.get();
    }
    const T* cend() const {
        return arrptr.get() + _size;
    }
    T* end() {
        return arrptr.get() + _size;
    }
};

int main() {
    badvector<int> b;
    b.reserve(30);
    cout << "size " << b.size() << endl << "capacity " << b.get_cp() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        b.push_back(42);
    }
    cout << "size after push_back: " << b.size() << endl << "capacity after push_back: " << b.get_cp() << endl;
    for (auto i = b.begin(); i != b.end(); i++) {
        cout << b[*i] << endl;
    }
}
```

I really don't know why this happens. Possibly one of the variant is initializing the arrays with nullptr?

Comment: Handy tool compiler option: `-fsanitize=address,undefined` If it's supported, it tells you exactly what happened and where when you run the program. That just leaves you to work out the why. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/vnhx3Wj1v

Comment: If you fill up the array then capacity counter will likely fail to find a zero within the valid bounds of the array. Worse, what happens if you write a legitimate zero into the array? Best to just keep track of the number of items placed in the vector as you place and remove them.

Answer (score 1):

So many things wrong with the code you have shown.

Why are you using a `shared_ptr` for the array?  You are not sharing it between instances of your class, and your code would behave quite badly if you actually did.  You should be using a `unique_ptr` instead.

Also, in your final loop of `main()`, you are treating each element of the vector as if they were indexes into the vector, which they are not.

But, most importantly, you don't seem to understand the difference between the *capacity* (number of allocated elements) and *size* (number of elements being used within the capacity). Your `_capacity` member does not accurately reflect how many elements you are allocating memory for. And you are using the `_capacity` member in places where you should be using the `_size` member instead, and vice versa.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class goodvector {
private:
    size_t _size;
    size_t _capacity;
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> arrptr;

public:
    goodvector() : _size(0), _capacity(5), arrptr(new T[5]) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _capacity; ++i) {
            arrptr[i] = T();
        }
    }

    ~goodvector() = default;

    goodvector(const goodvector&) = delete;
    goodvector(goodvector&&) = delete;
    goodvector& operator=(const goodvector&) = delete;
    goodvector& operator=(goodvector&&) = delete;

    size_t capacity() const {
        return _capacity;
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return _size;
    }

    void push_back(T arg) {
        if (_capacity == _size) {
            reserve(_size + 5);
        }
        arrptr[_size] = std::move(arg);
        ++_size; 
    }

    void reserve(size_t sz) {
        if (sz <= _capacity) return;
        std::unique_ptr<T[]> temp(new T[sz]);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _size; ++i) {
            temp[i] = arrptr[i];
        }
        for (size_t i = _size; i < sz; ++i) {
            temp[i] = T();
        }
        arrptr = std::move(temp);
        _capacity = sz;
    }

    void resize(size_t sz) {
        if (sz == _size) return;
        if (sz < _size) {
            for(size_t i = sz; i < _size; ++i) {
                arrptr[i] = T();
            }
        }
        else {
            reserve(sz);
        }
        _size = sz;
    }

    T operator[](size_t position) const {
        if (position >= _size) {
            throw out_of_range("out of range");
        }
        return arrptr[position];
    }

    void print(size_t position) const {
        if (position >= _size) {
            throw out_of_range("out of range");
        }
        cout << arrptr[position] << endl;
    }

    const T* cbegin() const {
        return arrptr.get();
    }

    T* begin() {
        return arrptr.get();
    }

    const T* cend() const {
        return arrptr.get() + _size;
    }

    T* end() {
        return arrptr.get() + _size;
    }
};

int main() {
    goodvector<int> b;
    b.reserve(30);
    cout << "size " << b.size() << endl << "capacity " << b.capacity() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
        b.push_back(42);
    }
    cout << "size after push_back: " << b.size() << endl << "capacity after push_back: " << b.capacity() << endl;
    for (auto iter = b.begin(); iter != b.end(); ++iter) {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }
}
```

Obviously, there is room for improvement (like not initializing array members that already initialize themselves), but this should give you the jist of how your vector should behave.